# Accidentally ran requirements.txt outside venv

Tags: python, pip

In the course I'm following we got a requirements.txt file that has to be run to get the required packages. I accidentally ran the txt outside a venv and it started deinstalling and installing a bunch of packages (probably because it's an older file with older versions). Did i ruin anything or is it not a big problem? If I ruined anything, is there a way to undo it? I'm still only practicing so it's not that I'm actively working on anything important. Also sorry if this is not an appropriate question, I just got a little scare when all those packages got reinstalled.

Comment: You simply modified your global environment - if you usually work inside a venv, just continue to do so. Later if/when you encounter global packages that don't satisfy some requirement, just reinstall it as needed.

Comment: Yeah sounds fair enough, thanks for your answer :)